# How to set hash instance's value like this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have two classes A and B, both of them have some options, normally I will use one Hash to store options like `@options[:name]='xxxx'`; now I want refactored it using meta programming,

```
class A
    set_option :name, "james"
    set_option :address, "some street"

    def hello
        puts @options[:name]
        puts @options[:address]
    end
end


class B
    set_option :age, 18

    def greeting
        put @options[:age]
    end
end
```

Here I want to use `set_option` to set key&value pairs to one hash instance `@options`, how can I do it?

Further I want to wrap the solution to a separate Module.

UPDATED:

thanks first,  all your answers are valuable to me and make me clearer, now I realize that some thing I want is not so correctly, so what if I make the question like this?

- how about using one method `option` to replace the `@options`?
- both classes A and B can set different option for one same key, so may be some answers' `@@options` will not work? I want different classes can have different hash instance.

```
like this:

```
class A
    set_option :name, "james"
    set_option :provider, 'twitter'

    def hello
        puts option[:name]
    end
end


class B
    set_option :name, "not james"

    def greeting
        put option[:name]
    end
end
```

After much thought I think What I really want is different option hash instance for different class, not class's instance.

Here is what I want and it can work.

```
module HasOptions
  def self.included(cls)
    cls.class_eval do
      def self.set_option(key, value)
        options[key] = value
      end

      def self.options
        @options ||= {}
      end

      def options
        self.class.options
      end
    end
  end
end


class Baz
  include HasOptions
  set_option :name, "bad"

  def greeting
        puts options[:name]
  end
end

class Foo
  include HasOptions
  set_option :name, "foo"

  def greeting
        puts options[:name]
  end
end
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 5):

Using an instance variable, as you are trying to do, won't work. However, you can use a method like this:

```
module HasOptions
  def self.included(cls)
    cls.class_eval do
      def self.set_option(key, value)
        (@@options ||= {})[key] = value
      end
    end
  end

  def options
    @options ||= @@options.dup
  end
end
```

This implementation allows you to set per-instance options, without overwriting the common options for all instances.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are messing things a little bit. Let me try to list the questions you want to be solved:

- store options in an instance of class variable `Hash` (did I got it correct?—one hash for all the instances of your classes);
- use a pretty notation for setting options.

Nothing of the above requires meta-programming actually. To satisfy first condition you are simply to find the first common ancestor of all your classes and [monkey]patch it with your `@@options` var and `set_option` method. If you did not decide to provide your own superclass for all your classes, let’s patch the very ancestor (e.g. `Kernel` module):

```
module Kernel
  def set_option name, value
    (@@options ||= {})[name.to_sym] = value
  end
end
```

Now any class may include `set_option` “instruction” to put option in *shared* options hash (consider using instance variable `@options` instead of `@@options` to make options instance-specific, or use the Alex D’s solution.)

If you want to have curly fancy syntax for option setting (with defaults, inplace checkers, ruches and luxury goods), you are to use [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) here. The first example in [this article](https://practicingruby.com/articles/shared/iptocucwujtj) shows how to implement pure `set_option` with DSL. The further tuning is only limited by your imagination.

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa, for your listed question items, the first one is not I want, I want different hash instances for different classes.

Comment: @donnior then simply get rid of double `@` in favour of `@options` in any solution suggested in comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want init instance options you should use instance methods to do it.

```
module OptionSetter
  def set_option(key, value)
    @options[key] = value
  end
end

class Base
  def initialize(options = {})
    @options = {}
    options.each do |key, value|
      set_option key, value
    end
  end
end

class A < Base
  include OptionSetter

  def hello
    puts @options[:name]
    puts @options[:address]
  end
end

class B < Base
  include OptionSetter

  def greeting
    puts @options[:age]
  end
end

A.new(name: "james", address: "some street").hello
B.new(age: 18).greeting
```

More common way to make it in ruby is using `attr_accessor`'s

```
class Base
  attr_accessor :options

  def initialize(options = {})
    @options = options
  end
end

class A < Base
  def hello
    puts @options[:name]
    puts @options[:address]
  end
end

class B < Base
  def greeting
    puts @options[:age]
  end
end

A.new(name: "james", address: "some street").hello
B.new(age: 18).greeting

# another approach
james = A.new
james.options[:name] = "james"
james.options[:address] = "some street"
james.hello
```